# Angular Material not support in Cumulocity environment

Tags: angular, angular-material, cumulocity

*Using Angular Material version 12 in Cumulocity IoT breaks the application design . In web every thing works fine but after deploying in Cumulocity IoT , the design breaks. It breaks when using self developed Widgets .Nothing of Material component works .
Suggest some solution to use Material in COT.*